# how stop indexing links with included subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, search, indexing, robots.txt

My real links on my website should index in google as (example):

> www.mywebsite.com/title,id,sometext,sometext

unexpectedly google search indexing my website with subfolders whitch should not occur for example:

> www.mywebsite.com/include/title,id,sometext,sometext
>   www.mywebsite.com/img/min/title,id,sometext,sometext
>   and so on

how can i stop these actions from indexing. What i have to change on htaccess or robots.txt? Help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your robots.txt to prevent bots from browsing those pages and you should set a noindex on these pages to remove them from rankings. You may also want to explore canonical links if the same page can be served from multiple URLs.